# clases y laravel collectible

Tags: laravel

Estoy implementando laravel collectible en un proyecyo y al generar un input tipo texto con la clase me da el siguiente error

> htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given

este es el codigo que estoy colocando en la vista

```
<div class="input-group mb-2"> {!! Form::text('ceula_paciente' , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</div>
```

pero es solo con este tipo de campo, por que en los campos de tipo

> password

si deja colocar el segundo parametro de clases.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel utilizas?

Comment: estoy trabajando con la versión 9

Comment: te falta el 2do argumento que es el value {{Form::text('name',null,[])}}

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora si funciona bien y si quisiera agregar un evento onclick?